# The popover arrow direction cannot be determined

Tags: ios, ios5, uikit, uipopovercontroller

I am using a `popover` that contains some input fields. Because the iOS keyboard covers large screen area, sometimes I need to correct the popups location (by moving its target and calling `-presentPopoverFromView:targetView` on the `popover`). I assume that I cannot determine the popup's view rectangle precisely but having the arrow direction and content size, I could approximate its current location.

The problem is that I am getting constantly unknown direction (`UIPopoverArrowDirectionUnknown`) even when the popup is clearly visible.

In iOS 5.1 UIKit.framework, header file `UIPopoverController.h` we can read that we can get the present direction of the `popover arrow` (one of up, down, left, right, unknown). The only condition is that the `popover` needs to be presented.

```
 /* Returns the direction the arrow is pointing on a presented popover. Before     presentation, this returns UIPopoverArrowDirectionUnknown.
  */
 @property (nonatomic, readonly) UIPopoverArrowDirection popoverArrowDirection;
```

We can determine if the popover is presented with a getter `isPopoverVisible`:

```
 /* Returns whether the popover is visible (presented) or not.
  */
 @property (nonatomic, readonly, getter=isPopoverVisible) BOOL popoverVisible;
```

But despite I can see the popover arrow aiming up or down etc. and the `myPopover.isPopoverVisible == YES`, the arrow direction is still `myPopover.popoverArrowDirection == UIPopoverArrowDirectionUnknown`.

The `popover` is presented by:

```
[self presentPopoverFromRect:sourceView.frame inView:sourceView.superview
    permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

EDIT (solution)

I had iOS 5.0.1 installed on my device (iPad). The compilation target was 5.1. After updating the device to 5.1 the problem disappeared completely.

Comment: If you've solved the problem, post an answer and mark it accepted, so the question doesn't appear as unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had iOS 5.0.1 installed on my device (iPad). The compilation target was 5.1. After updating the device to 5.1 the problem disappeared completely.